# Excel formula to add rank column in excel sheet based on two columns and filter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to add rank column in my excel sheet based on Date and grouped by type and only Consider Status = Active

Here is the sample table:

| Status | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Active | 1 Bedroom | 1/5/2024 |
| Active | 1 Bedroom | 1/1/2024 |
| Inactive | Studio | 12/31//2023 |
| Active | Studio | 1/4/2024 |
| Active | Studio | 12/30/2023 |

I want to add a rank column based on Date so for example for 1 bedroom the rank for 1/5 will be 2 and for 1/1 will be 1 and then for studio 12/31 the rank is 1. Here is the desired output:

| Status | Type | Date | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Active | 1 Bedroom | 1/5/2024 | 2 |
| Active | 1 Bedroom | 1/1/2024 | 1 |
| Inactive | Studio | 12/31//2023 |  |
| Active | Studio | 1/4/2024 | 2 |
| Active | Studio | 12/30/2023 | 1 |

I tried

```
=If(A2 = "Active", COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<="&B2),'')
```

but it did not work as expected.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would need to add the condition to the COUNTIFS also:

```
=IF(A2 = "Active", COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,"<="&C2,A:A,"Active"),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using SUMPRODUCT, you can add all 3 conditions, nested in the IF statement.

```
=IF(A2 = "Active", SUMPRODUCT((A2 = A:A) * (B2 = B:B) * (C2 > C:C)) + 1, "")
```

[image]